# IronClad equivalent for Jython

Tags: python, c, ironpython, jython, ironclad

For IronPython there is a project - [IronClad](http://www.resolversystems.com/documentation/index.php/Ironclad), that aims to transparently run C extensions in it. Is there a similiar project for Jython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep an eye on JyNI (http://www.jyni.org), which is to Jython exactly what is Ironclad to IronPython. As of this writing JyNI is still alpha state though.

If you just want to use some C-library from Jython, simply use JNA from Jython like you would do from Java. If you need finer control, look at JNI or SWIG.

Also, you might want to take a look at JEP (https://github.com/mrj0/jep) or JPY (https://github.com/bcdev/jpy).

Comment: There is also JNR, which I forgot to mention. It is probably the better alternative to JNA as it is said to be much more performant.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use Java's loadLibrary to do that (provided it works in your platform's java). It is in the java library: [java.System.loadLibrary()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary(java.lang.String)).

Note that sometimes you will have to write a wrapper in C and/or in Java depending on the library you want to use and target system, since details are platform dependant.
Refer to the documentation for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it was not what I was looking for. Propably it means that there is no similiar project in the Jython world.

Comment: Maybe not what you were hoping for, but there is pretty much no other way to do it. Jython is locked up to what java can do.